# Qt subclassing from QWidget

Tags: qt, subclassing

I write my own class which subclass from QWidget
And this is my header file

```
#ifndef GRAPHMATRIX_H
#define GRAPHMATRIX_H

#include "treemodel.h"
#include <QWidget>
#include <Qt/qtableview.h>

class GraphMatrix : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TreeModel& getModel();
    GraphMatrix(QWidget* parent = 0);
    void addTop(QString name);
    void cutComponent(GraphMatrix* component, QVector<int> columns);
private:
    TreeModel model;
    QTableView* view;
public slots:
    void changeValue(const QModelIndex& index);
};

#endif // GRAPHMATRIX_H
```

And I am getting this error

```
error C2248: 'QWidget::QWidget' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QWidget'
```

Can anyone help me?

**Updated to add:** I find answer, problem is in QList I must write QList. because QList is using copy constructor. Thank you for giving time for my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in `QList<GraphMatrix>`, I must write `QList<GraphMatrix*>`, because `QList` is using a copy constructor.

Comment: I edited this into the original question, so that people won't waste their time on it. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Sounds like you were doing `QList<GraphMatrix>` when you should have been doing `QList<GraphMatrix*>`  It's generally not a good idea to keep lists of QObjects that aren't pointers.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to call the default constructor of QWidget which is private. Instead, your constructor needs to call the public constructor of QWidget as follows:

```
GraphMatrix::GraphMatrix(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent) {}
```

Comment: But QWidget *does* have a constructor that takes no arguments (or rather, it takes arguments but provides defaults).

Comment: I guess he's trying to access something else that is private. We'll have to wait until he posts more code.